# Finding vectors

Tags: math, opengl, algebra

Given a vector V = (x, y, z), how do i find 2 vector that make up an axis with V ? In other words, one of them is perpendicular and lies in the same plane, and the other is normal to those two vectors.

I need this to implement a nice camera manager in OpenGL.

Comment: Good questions, just http://math.stackexchange.com/ will probably give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given only one vector you can find and infinite number of vectors being perpendicular to it. In particular this set of vectors forms a plane to which your given vector is normal to.

Given some vector not colinear with the first one, you can find a perpendicular (=orthogonal) vector by applying [Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process). Let your first vector be **↑v**, and **↑u** is some vector so that ↑u =/= l ↑v, then a perpendicularized ↑u_ = ↑u - ↑v ( ↑u · ↑v)

Answer (score 0):

This question really is off topic for StackOverFlow, but I have a minute. You are asking to form a triad of orthogonal vectors, two of which are orthogonal to your given vector. The simplest way to do so is to use a QR decomposition.

I'll do it in MATLAB, which does the linear algebra nicely. Start with some arbitrary column vector v.

```
v = [1 2 3]'
v =

     1
     2
     3
```

The QR decomposition of that array with one column only results in matrices Q and R. We need only Q.

```
[Q,R] = qr(v);
```

The columns of Q give you what you need.

```
Q =

  -0.267261241912424   -0.534522483824849   -0.801783725737273
  -0.534522483824849    0.774541920588438   -0.338187119117343
  -0.801783725737273   -0.338187119117343    0.492719321323986
```

See that the first column is simply v, scaled to be a "unit" vector. We can also multiply by -1 arbitrarily in a set of axes, on any axis, if you don't like the orientation produced. The second and third columns of this matrix are unit vectors orthogonal to the given vector.

Of course, this is not the only way you might have done it. For example, one could choose any two other random vectors, then use Gram-Schmidt to orthogonalize the set of three vectors. That is a valid scheme, as long as random chance did not yield some vectors that are a linearly dependent set when you started. So it is possible for that algorithm to fail, although extremely unlikely.

Another scheme effectively uses not much more than a pair of cross products. Thus, given some vector v1:

1. Choose v2 randomly.
2. Using a cross product, set v3=cross(v1,v2). If the norm of vector v3 is zero, then return to step 1, as that implies vectors v1 and v2 were collinear.
3. Set v2 = cross(v1,v3).

This algorithm is a simple one, that really has some similarities to a Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization, but it is fairly simple to write. You need to be careful with the test in step 2, as testing to see if a number is exactly zero is not a good idea. You probably also want to scale your vectors to have unit norm as you compute them, as that will solve some numerical issues.

In the end, I still prefer use of the QR factorization, as it is simple, requires no tests for "zero", and thus no explicit tolerances are needed.

Comment: Hi. Actually my problem has no solution. I didn't express my problem correctly. There are an infinite number of possible axis for a given vector, but i was thinking about a particular one that can't be found, except if i store the initial matrix state. But if i do something like camera.set_position(...), i lose the state and i can't determine the other two missing axis...